# 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:

Tags: php

```
class User{
    private $db;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new Database();
    }

    public function userRegistration($data){
            $name = $data['name'];
            $email = $data['email'];
            $username = $data['uid'];          
            $password = $data['pwd'];
            $confirm_pass = $data['pwd2'];
            $phn = $data['phn'];
            $dob = $data['dob'];
            $blood = $data['blood'];
            $religion = $data['rlgn'];
            $address = $data['addrs'];
            $country = $data['cntry'];

            $chk_email = $this->emailCheck($email);

            //Check empty field
            if($name == '' OR $username == '' OR $email == '' OR $password == '' OR $phn == ''){
                $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Must not be empty!!</div>";
                return $msg;
            }

            //Check password confirmation
             if(!$password == $confirm_pass){
                $msg = "<p>Password didn't match!</p>";
            }else{
                $password = md5($data['pwd']);
            }

            //Email validation
            if(filtet_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
                $msg = "<p>Email address is not valid!!</p>";
                return $msg;
            }

            //Eamil check in database
            if($chk_email == true){
                $msg = "<p>Already exist!!</p>";
                return $msg;
            }

    }

    public function emailCheck(){
                $sql = "SELECT email from user_info WHERE email = :email";
                $query = $this->db->pdo->prepare($sql);
                $query->bindParam(" :email", $email);
                $query->execute();
                    if($query->rowCount() > 0){
                        return true;
                    } else{
                        return false;
                    }
    }
}
```

I am trying to check for existing email in database with submitted one, but the code given above results in error just like  **SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:** WITH A PDOException saying parameter was not defined. I am not too much familiar with OOP approach in PHP. But trying to connect database with a class having PDO features.

WHATS GOING ON HERE??

Comment: I've never seen a bindParam statement declare a parameter name like `" :email"`, try `":email"` instead (note the space is removed). Also, change `public function emailCheck()` to `public function emailCheck($email)`.

Comment: not certain , you can check : " :email" has extraneous space chr.

Comment: So that public function emailCheck($email) saved my day!! Thank you.